# mobile device - different background - media query not working

Tags: css, mobile, background, media-queries

[Live site.](http://parlourdc.com/wp)

This is my first attempt at utilizing a different CSS for mobile devices vs. regular screens. 
To do this, I'm using-

```
@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        background: url('img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working (I can only test on iPhones). Any ideas as to why that may be? I've also tried `@media all` to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? Have you tried just using a solid `background-color` to see if maybe it's an issue with your image?

Comment: your not targeting an HTML element in that code?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yep, changing to `background:red;` had no effect.

Comment: @cih what do you mean? as i mentioned, this is my first attempt. i despite reading several tutorials, i may very well have missed something.

Comment: @AMC -- If you don't specify what element you want styled, the browser doesn't know where to apply the style. Even if you want to apply it to "the whole page", you still need to specify the `html` or `body` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
         body{
           background: url('img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
           background-size: cover;
           height: 100%;
         }
}
```

The body is the HTML element that you are targeting so assuming you have a `<body>` tag in your HTML the CSS styles above will be applied when the device meets the width criteria.

EDIT : Also try the background like this, if the file is there should work...

```
background: transparent url(/img/background.jpg/) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

EDIT : Turns out an `!important` tag fixed this issue, you can read more about CSS precedence [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

Comment: Ah, yep. That makes sense. However, making those changes still didn't alter the mobile background?

Comment: hmm.. is the file path correct? does the solid background color work like Roddy suggested? Try www.yoururl.com/img/background.jpg

Comment: The file path is definitely correct. I've tried using a solid color, as well as `html` instead of `body`, no changes.

Comment: Can I see the HTML? Im assuming you have something in the <body> try adding... height:200px; width: 200px; if the body is empty.

Comment: Everything has been broken down into php for Wordpress at this point. Is that an issue?

Comment: You can view source though right? I use similar code to that above and it works fine for me. I would reccomend trying to change the style of something else on the page based on that media query to confirm the problem lies with the CSS. It could be a precedence/inheritance issue check out this link http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/ maybe try an !important tag but dont give up you will get it!